# How can i apply rules to outlook using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook

I am trying to extract emails from outlook to be run through supervised classification. From there, if the email falls into a specific classification, it should have a generic response for that email based on the classification. The problem I am facing is on how to extract the emails and reply to them. I am using win32com library to extract successfully but will need to change to another method because not all the computers running this project will have python installed. If possible, i would like it to work like outlook rules but a special AI rule. What methods are available to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: What is the classification? The possible methods will depend on what you need to track to choose the automatic response.

Comment: Hi Jim, supervised text multi-classification

Comment: If I understand correctly, either you need to access all accounts from a python-capable computer or server, or this might be a task for a VBA script. Have you considered scripting the macro in Outlook VBA?